# Managing View Controllers to maintain state

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, viewcontroller

Fundamental question about how to navigate between View Controllers. Say I have VC "A" and VC "B", both are embedded in a Navigation Controller. To go from A to B, I use a segue. After I get to B, I click a button that makes some visual change, like the color of the button. Then I hit the Nav Controller's back button to Unwind, and get back to A. Then I use the segue again to go to B, and I get a NEW VC "B" - WITHOUT the new button color. I guess that's how segues work.

But how do I instead get the same VC B, with the new button color?

My hack is to save off an instance variable of the VC B (in VC A's class), and navigate to it using navigationController.pushViewController(). Tests confirm that my button-color changes remain between invocations of B. But this solution feels clunky and hacky.

So, before I flesh this code out, I need to ask: is there a design pattern for going A->B->A->B and NOT getting a new B the second time? What's the preferred method?

Comment: You don't save the old VC B. You ensure that your data model object is updated so that the new VC B can render its views correctly.

Comment: You might also consider something besides a navigation controller. Sounds like what you want is closer to a tab bar controller that keeps each root view controller. Or maybe you need to build your own view controller that can toggle between A & B.

Comment: Thanks Paul. So you're saying that every time I make a change, I have to save it off? Some of these things don't even have variables to store them, they're so fleeting -- things like which items in a table I've selected. I'm trying to not have to save everything off.

Comment: Thanks Picciano. I notice that my VC A does look a lot like a set of tabs! Maybe that's what I need. It's really just 4 big buttons to take you to 4 different VCs.

Answer (score 3):

When you push to view controller B, an instance of B is created and that is what you push to. When you pop back to view controller A, that instance of view controller B is deinitialized, gone forever. When you push back to view controller B, you create a new instance. Therefore, for the color of the button to remain unchanged, you need to preserve the state of view controller B so that all of its instances will reflect that change. There are a number of ways to preserve state, the option you choose will be determined by the project and personal preference.

Answer (score 1):

`UINavigationController` deallocates the popped view controller (VC B), so when you attempt to push VC B again, its a new instance is created. *Unless* You hold a strong reference to VC B in VC A. This is not recommend but VC A remains in the navigation stack so if it holds a reference to VC B, that instance could be pushed back in.

The recommend way would be to get the states you want to maintain when popping VC B and set them back when pushing on the new VC B instance.

**Solution 1 (not recommended):**

```
class VCA: UIViewController {
    lazy var vcB: VCB = VCB()

    func presentVCB() {
        navigationController?.pushViewController(vcB, animated: true)
    }
}

class VCB: UIViewController {
    var someState: String = ""
}
```

**Solution 2, Use delegation:**

```
class VCA: UIViewController, VCBDelegate {

    // This could be any data-structure in which you can store the states in VC B
    var lastVCBState: String?

    func presentVCB() {
        let vcB: VCB = VCB()
        vcB.delegate = self
        lastVCBState != nil ? vcB.someState = lastVCBState! : ()
        navigationController?.pushViewController(vcB, animated: true)
    }

    // MARK: VCBDelegate
    func didPopWith(state: String) {
        lastVCBState = state
    }
}

protocol VCBDelegate: class {
    func didPopWith(state: String)
}

class VCB: UIViewController {
    weak var delegate: VCBDelegate?

    // Any data-structure in which you can store the states
    var someState: String = ""

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        delegate?.didPopWith(state: someState)
    }
}
```

Comment: Solution 3: use the Coordinator pattern.

Answer (score 1):

**Step1:** When you change the color of the bottom save it on any persistent way. 
For example Singleton Class or NSUserDefaults.

**Step2:** Load the saved color in your VCB.

**Example using Singleton Class:**

```
class VCB: UIViewController {

   @IBOutlet weak var myButton: UIButton!

   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        self.myButton.backgroundColor = UIHelper.sharedInstance.VCBButtonColor
   }

   @IBAction func changeColorButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
      //Save in the color in singleton class
      UIHelper.sharedInstance.VCBButtonColor = UIColor.green
   }
}

//Singleton Class
class UIHelper: NSObject {
    var VCBButtonColor = UIColor.red
    static let sharedInstance = UIHelperClass()    

    override init() {
       ...
    }
}
```

Note: When you use a singleton class and you kill the app, you lost your saved color.

**Example using User Defaults:**

```
class VCB: UIViewController {

   @IBOutlet weak var myButton: UIButton!

   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
          if let savedColor = UserDefaults.standard.color(forKey: "SavedColor") {
             self.myButton.backgroundColor = savedColor
          }
   }

   @IBAction func changeColorButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
       UserDefaults.standard.set(color: UIColor.red, forKey: "SavedColor")
   }
}

extension UserDefaults {
   func color(forKey key: String) -> UIColor? {
      var color: UIColor?
      if let colorData = data(forKey: key) {
         color = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: colorData) as? UIColor
      }
      return color
   }

   func set(color: UIColor?, forKey key: String) {
      var colorData: NSData?
      if let color = color {
         colorData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: color) as NSData?
      }
      set(colorData, forKey: key)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Segue between viewControllers can be done using a "navigationController" as an entry point from which you can segue to root VCA then to VCB. In this case all states of VC are preserved (but gyro & accelerometers, I think). That works fine in all my applications even those using scene animations :-)

Alex